# Как задать iframe src при помощи javascript

Tags: html, javascript

Есть Iframe

```
<iframe src="" name="iframe1" id='iframe1'>
</iframe>
```

Как при помощи java script задать src айфрейму? Что-то типа:

```
function IFrame1() {
    document.getElementById('iframe1').contentWindow="1.html";
}
```

-

```
<div onClick="IFrame1()" class='Menu3'>
1 страница
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function IFrame1() {
    document.getElementById('iframe1').src="http://hashcode.ru";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function IFrame1() {
    document.getElementById('iframe1').setAttribute('src', '1.html');
}
```